# PJSIP TLS verify error (PJSIP_TLS_ECERTVERIF)

Tags: ssl, certificate, voip, pjsip, verify

I have recently started to develop a tiny SIP softphone application using the PJ Project and GTK+. My main goal was to create a softphone which supports both TLS and SRTP encryption (and MWI). However I have got stuck right at the part where the library registers an account because the application has failed to verify the server when I asked it for it.
I thought that I misunderstood something while I was coding as I'm a newbie but today I've just tested the library using the PJSUA application which was attached in the source code and it could register my SIP account unless I've started the program with the --tls-verify-server flag.
To make it clear I've created for Asterisk my own certificate authority, keys and certificate and I've installed the CA to my machine.
I must note that this setup works with a commercial software, it can verify the certificate without any problem.

The PJSUA flags I've used:

```
--use-tls
--tls-ca-file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
--id=sip:u-kuklinistvan1@kingdom.info.tm;transport=tls
--registrar=sip:kingdom.info.tm;transport=tls
--realm=kingdom.info.tm
--username=u-kuklinistvan1
--password=xxxxxx
--use-srtp=2
--mwi
--tls-verify-server
```

It says([please follow the link for the long version](http://pastebin.com/ri67e1NF)):

```
19:21:44.728    pjsua_app.c  TLS cert verification result of [94.21.11.229:5061] : The server identity does not match to any identities specified in the certificate
```

...which could not be true as OpenSSL itself accepts the certificate:

```
openssl s_client -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt -connect kingdom.info.tm:5061
```

[(click here for the rest)](http://pastebin.com/Q5uaWYyb)

```
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

**Extra information**
I connect PJSUA as endpoint to registrar by hostname kingdom.info.tm.

Is it possible that I've encountered a bug or I just don't understand something?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> ... does not match to any identities specified in the certificate
>
> ... which could be not true as OpenSSL itself accepts the certificate: ... `openssl s_client ...`

The error messages refers to checking the identity against the certificate, i.e. the hostname you provide against the names in the certificate (subject alternative names, common name). `openssl s_client` does not do any identity checks but only checks for a valid trust chain.

Looking at the certificate provided by the server it actually contains contain a common name for `kingdom.info.tm`. But from the error message it looks that it expects the IP address: `TLS cert verification result of [94.21.11.229:5061]: ...`. Did you specify the SIP URL of the peer with an IP address?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Theoretically I've specified the domain in my SIP URI as you see (--id=sip:u-kuklinistvan1@kingdom.info.tm;transport=tls). Is it possible that it is because of the name resolution? Unfortunately I have dynamic IP address so I can assign my certificate only to a domain in the long term.

Comment: I don't understand. Not your own IP should be relevant for the certificate but the name of the host you connect to as proxy or endpoint (i.e. the server side of the connection). I think you must use the TLS connection to a proxy (with a proper certificate) and can not use a direct connection since then you don't have a certificate matching the endpoint.

Comment: Excuse me for confusing the things: this is my own server, it is on my LAN and port 5061 has been forwarded. This setup works with the application CSipSimple for Android even using the home LAN and even using the mobile network that is the network is configured correctly. The server uses a certificate which is validated by my own CA which I've created for this purpose and this CA is installed on my Android smartphone.

Comment: I only saw that you are using public domains for your credentials. If this is your own server you need to have a fixed name for it which then can be put into the certificate and which you use to access the server. This might be a fixed IP (which you don't have) or some constant name for your dynamic IP which you might get from DynDNS provider.

Comment: This domain has been created using the service of freedns.afraid.org, and the server updates the IP address of the domain regularly that is in this moment kingdom.info.tm points to my network so it should be okay. I used to use DynDNS by the way. Does using FreeDNS or DynDNS makes a difference?

Comment: It does not matter who provides the service, but it is important that you access the peer with the hostname contained in the certificate and not an IP. From your question I can see how you identify yourself, but not how you specify the target and if there is a proxy involved. Note that the certificate must identify the SIP peer correctly, which is either the proxy or the other phone directly.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand. The domain kingdom.info.tm is assigned to my IP address and I can connect through this address to the host. For example there is an Apache server running on the host and if I type kingdom.info.tm to my web browser then the content of index.html appears. The situation is the same for SIP-TLS: the server is listening on kingdom.info.tm:5061 . Do you mean that the certificate must contain in the field common name sip:kingdom.info.tm instead of kingdom.info.tm .

Comment: All I see is that it looks like that it uses the wrong name (maybe the IP) for verification and not kingdom.info.tm. Therefore my question is which name you use for the target phone and if there is a proxy involved and which name you use to access it. These information are not contained in your question.

Comment: I don't use a domain or name for the target phone - which is now my machine - as I'd like to serve dynamic hosts over the internet. I don't even use certificates for the clients (or peers) only for the server because as far as I know it is enough to encrypt the password and the SRTP signaling.

Comment: With TLS the peer has to identity itself with the certificate and the certificate must match the name of the peer you use to contact it. If you present a certificate not matching the host name you use to access the peer then it fails. Again, it is not clear from your question how you access the peer.

Comment: I think I have to make the concepts clear for myself. According to http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+SIP+user+vs+peer I rather have to say I have users(type=friend, host=dynamic) on the server, not peers. In this case I have a username, a password and a CA certificate to verify the server and that's all. As I imagine the client creates the connection then the server sends its public key which PJSUA verifies using the CA. If it went correctly then PJSUA does a handshake and then sends the username and the password and Asterisk registers the softphone.

Comment: SIP does not have the general concept of servers, but of proxies, registrars and endpoints. A TLS connection can be done between endpoint and registrar, endpoint and proxy and endpoint and endpoint. In each case the peer of the connection needs to have a valid certificate which matches the hostname used to access the peer. From your question it is neither clear when this error happens (connect to proxy, registrar or endpoint) nor how you access this host (by IP, by host name, which host name).

Comment: The error happens when I connect PJSUA as endpoint to registrar by hostname kingdom.info.tm.

Comment: Then I don't understand why this happens either. The certificate looks fine for me and the certificate check in PJSUA source code looks fine too.

Comment: Isn't it a problem that the endpoint does not have a certificate? Or is this possible because PJSIP doesn't support wild-card domains and it influences somehow subdomains as well? (and I have to mention that it neither works in my application nor in PJSUA, the error is the same)

Comment: You say that the problem happens when accessing the registrar as  kingdom.info.tm, in which case only the registrar needs the certificate. But there is a matching non-wildcard certificate at this host port 5061 and the only reason I could imagine is that it somehow does not use the name of  kingdom.info.tm to check this certificate but something else.

Comment: Absolutely this is the situation, it was only hard to explain because of the lack of my knowledge. So you say that it forgets the domain after the name resolution and tries to compare the IP address? If this happens what can I do from here? Should I choose another SIP library? I should mention that the application CSipSimple which uses PJSIP library has overcome this problem, but only in the specific OpenSSL build (https://nightlies.csipsimple.com/specific_builds/). As far as I remember in the normal release ssl didn't work at all.

Comment: It might be an issue with the version of the library you use (do you use the latest?). Unless you feel comfortable of debugging the issue by tracing the program flow inside the library itself I would suggest that you look for another library. Of course it is no guarantee that the other library will work better.

Comment: The library which is in the repository of Ubuntu is version 2.1 but when I've run in to this problem I've compiled version 2.3 and the problem is still present. As I'm not a programmer and it is only a hobby for me I can't debug the library but maybe I'll send bug report later. Thank you for your help!